# basic parallel programming concept: cost of search with N processors

Tags: parallel-processing

I am asking this question to make sure some concept of parallel computing concept.

Lets give a simple example: We have a set of `n` numbers, what's the best running time to search a item from it if we have at least `n/3` parallel computers?

I think this will still be `O(n)`, but not sure if I am right. Since the constant part of the big-Oh expression can be erased?

Thank you

Comment: Each computer searches 3 items. That's O(1). Then again, collecting the results is O(n) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be O(1) or O(ln n).

Given each of your n/3 computers n/(n/3) numbers; they all get essentially 3 values.  It takes them individually constant time to search their constant sized-set and return a result ("0 --> not found", k if found at the kth position in the array, if each is given K*(n/3) as the index in an array to start).   So, the value is *found* in time O(1).

The issue comes in reporting the answer.  Something has choose among the responses from the n/3 machines to pick a unique result.  Typically this requires a "repeated" choice among the subsets of machines, which you can do in O(n) time but in parallel systems is often done with a "reduction" operator (such as SUM or MAX or ...).  Such reduction operators can be (and usually are) implemented using a reduction *tree*, which is logarithmic.

Some parallel hardware has very fast reduction hardware, but is it still logarithmic.
  Weirdly enough, if you have n/1000 CPUs, you'll still get O(1) search times (with a big constant), and O(ln n) reduction times with a very small constant.  It'll "look" like constant time if you ignore the O notation.

Comment: Also, if it's a simple search to determine presence, you could take "whoever reports first" (if you just need a simple yes or no) and ignore everyone else; which is essentially `O(1)` for "present" (but pretty bad for "absent"); i.e. guaranteed `O(1)` if you know the thing is in there but just want to find the first occurence. If you don't know it's in there, you have to wait for everyone to report.

Answer (score 0):

This strictly depends on the underlying parallel model. Indeed, the final reduction step in which every processor defines a flag *Found x* and all processors perform a parallel reduction   may have a different complexity. See in particular the COMMON CRCW PRAM case.

For a message-passing setting:

- T(n) = O(n/p + log p) for p < n
- T(n) = O(log n) for p = O(n)

For a shared-memory setting:

a) EREW PRAM

- T(n) = O(n/p + log p) for p < n
- T(n) = O(log n) for p = O(n)

b) CREW PRAM

concurrent reads do not help: the final reduction step still takes O(log p) time anyway

- T(n) = O(n/p + log p) for p < n
- T(n) = O(log n) for p = O(n)

c) COMMON CRCW PRAM

concurrent writes really help: the final reduction step takes now O(1) time, those processors with the flag *Found x* set can write simultaneously the same value in a shared location

- T(n) = O(n/p) for p < n
- T(n) = O(1) for p = O(n)